# Flask Model ,how go get column value based on column id

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask ,most time I use Django and like Django.

I want to return the survey's name through its id:

Model:

```
class Survey(Base):
    __tablename__ = "survey "
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "st"}

    survey_id = sa.Column(sa.TEXT(length=50), primary_key=True)
    survey_name = sa.Column(sa.TEXT(length=100), nullable=False)

@app.route('/survey/<survey_id>',methods=['GET'])
def show_survey(survey_id):
    # Greet the survey
    survey = models.Survey.query.get(survey_id)
    return f'Hello {survey.name} !'
```

error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Survey' has no attribute 'get'
```

Any friend can help ?